# How to custom laravel passport error message?

Tags: laravel, message, laravel-passport

When I use laravel5.3's Passport [Password Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens)

```
this.$http.post('/oauth/token', this.form)
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response)
     })
```

I get this message

```
{"error":"invalid_credentials","message":"The user credentials were incorrect."}
```

**I want to know how to custom this error message.**

Comment: this is  message send by `vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Exception\OAuthServerException.php` line:120

Answer (score 5):

According [@driesvints](https://github.com/driesvints) in [#937](https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/937) Laravel Passport is working to develop a simplified way to customize Passport's errors. Until then you can use the following codes. I tested them and use them.

1. In page   `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`  add:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController;

...
```

```php
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind( AccessTokenController::class, \App\myOAuth\AccessTokenController::class);
    }
```

2. Make this page: `App\myOAuth\AccessTokenController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\myOAuth;

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController as PassportAccessTokenController;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response as Psr7Response;

class AccessTokenController extends PassportAccessTokenController
{
    /**
     * Authorize a client to access the user's account.
     *
     * @param  ServerRequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException
     */
    public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        try {
            return $this->server->respondToAccessTokenRequest($request, new Psr7Response);
        } catch (ClientException $exception) {
            $error = json_decode($exception->getResponse()->getBody());

            throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('access_token', object_get($error, 'error.message'));
        }
    }
}
```

3. In `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`  add your customized Exceptions

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

    ...

    $class = get_class($exception);

    ...


        if ($class == 'League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException' ){
            return response()->json([
              'code'=>$exception->getHttpStatusCode(),
              'error'=>$exception->getMessage(),
              'error_type'=>$exception->getErrorType()
            ],
            $exception->getHttpStatusCode());
        } 

        ...

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to modify the message when the user is inactive, or hasn't completed the registration.

There is a function that Passport uses for check user authentication "**validateForPassportPasswordGrant**", so, first I added the validation in the **User** model, and there, I throw the exception if the user is not active, which passport uses for the message. Then, it continues with the normal password validation.

```
public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
{
    if($this->status != 'ACTIVE') throw new 
    OAuthServerException('Your user is not active', '401', 'inactive_user');
    return Hash::check($password, $this->password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer at [laravel/passport github](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/289#issuecomment-312233456) issues. All it takes is replace Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController with different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution solved Laravel version 8 with `"flugger/laravel-responder": "^3.1"` package.

1. Install the [flugger/laravel-responder package](https://github.com/flugg/laravel-responder)
2. After installed. publish the package.

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Flugg\Responder\ResponderServiceProvider"
```

3. you can check the `app\config\responder.php` file.

```
...
    'serializers' => [
        'success' => Flugg\Responder\Serializers\SuccessSerializer::class,
        'error' => \Flugg\Responder\Serializers\ErrorSerializer::class,
    ],
...
```

This config is the path to the format class .you can make your own custom formate class. Just create and override the function in them.

4. create your own Exception handler.

```
php artisan make:exception NotLoginException
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Flugg\Responder\Exceptions\Http\HttpException;
class NotLoginException extends HttpException
{

    protected $status = 401;
    /**
     * The error code.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $errorCode = '401';

    /**
     * The error message.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $message = 'User not logged in.';

}
```

5. In `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`. Override the function `render`:

```
// don't forget to use these class; 
...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;
use Flugg\Responder\Exceptions\ConvertsExceptions;
use Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\OAuthServerException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
...

public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        $this->convertDefaultException($e);

        if($e instanceof OAuthServerException) {
            throw new PermissionDenyException();
        }

    
        if (
            $e instanceof NotLoginException ) {
            // you don't have always to do this. you can render your own Excption here.
            return $this->renderResponse($e);

        }
       
        
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

6. Notice that the `OAuthServerException` is just one of the `passport` exception. I am not sure that if there's other exceptions for `passport`.
   To check the exception type. Just use `get_class($e);` in render function. Then you can see the class type of exception. So, you are able to handle it.
7. you can see result

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": "401",
        "message": "User not logged in."
    }
}
```